# Xilinx MicroBlaze Floating Point Compatibility

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, fpga, xilinx

I have a 'c' code targeted to a MicroBlaze CPU.
When I debug the code as c program in Eclipse + GCC or Visual Studio I get the results I want.
Yet when I run on the target the result are different.

It happens only on floating point operations (Multiplication and Division).

How can I make it work with full floating point precision?

Are there special GCC flags?

P.S.
The configuration of the MicroBlaze is with all the hardware of floating point operations enabled.

Comment: What typedefs are you using? Specifically, what are the float lengths?  Are they the same across both tests? (32 bits, I assume?)

Comment: I use C singles. I don't use any typedefs. Only simple operations on singles.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to check that the ublaze results are correct?

Comment: ModelSim. I run the whole VHDL on ModelSim. I use the inputs from the ModelSim for the code on Eclipse / Visual Studio. Then I compare the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced with MicroBlaze, but [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroBlaze) states:

> Also, key processor instructions which are rarely used but more expensive to implement in hardware can be selectively added/removed (i.e. multiply, divide, and **floating-point ops**.)

Emphasis mine.

So, make sure that your particular MicroBlaze actually has the floating point operations supported, otherwise I imagine your results will be very random.

Also make sure your compiler toolchain generates the proper instructions, sometimes toolchains for embedded development support software-emulated floating point. This should be trivial to figure out by disassembling the final code, and seeing how the floating-point operations are implemented.

Comment: Floating point operations are enabled. They are just not as accurate as in the other platforms though they should. Since I am using feedback system after enough iterations the results diverge significantly.

Answer (score 1):

MicroBlaze floating-point in hardware supports IEEE754 with some exceptions that is listed in the MicroBlaze reference guide.

Floating-point is not 100% identical on all machines.
It depends on actual precision when executing the operations (hardware can use extended precision when executing single-precision operations), it also depends on the configuration of the rounding-mode (IEEE defines four different rounding modes).

MicroBlaze do not support denormalized floating-point (they will be consider to be zero).
However normal coding should avoid denormalized values since they have a reduced accuracy.

What kind of difference do you see?

Göran Bilski

Answer (score 1):

Hey had the same Problem. Yes there are special gcc flags but they should be set automatically when exporting the Hardware from Vivado. You can check this (Vivado SDK 2019.1) at

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Microblaze gcc compiler > Inferred Options > Processor Options
```

and

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Microblaze gcc linker > Inferred Options > Processor Options
```

Regardless of these Settings the results should represent your wanted results in some form. The standard lib should emulate the floating-point arrithmetic even if there is no FPU avaliable.

Have you linked the math library (-lm)?
Because i had the same problem with weird results and 0 as output of standard math functions on the target machine, without compile time errors. After i linked 'm' the behaviour was as expected.
You can do that in the Vivado SDK in

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Microblaze gcc linker > Libraries > -l > "m"
```

.